# Executing a function rendered using python-django

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, django-allauth

I am working with django-allauth for Google authentication implementation. I have successfully implemented it. In my current implementation, the form is rendered using django and I have implemented the URL for Google login as follows:

```
<a href="{% provider_login_url 'google' action='reauthenticate'%}">Login uisng Google</a>
```

If I want my browser to execute the `provider_login_url` automatically on window load using JavaScript, how can I do so? I want to know how to execute such python functions using javascript.

Comment: Execute this when the page loads: `document.getElementById('yourAElementIdHere').click()`

Comment: Thanks a lot @RoryMcCrossan for the help.